# R -If statement issues

Tags: r

I am looking to create a new column called TERM_COMBINED based on whether the title has been duplicated or not. I have created a duplicate flag in Excel using the COUNTIF function and brought that into R (I am not sure how to do this in R yet).

Below is a random data set to illustrate what I am looking to do.

```
title          Term   Duplicate
RandomWord      A      0
RanWord         B      1
RanWord         A      1
Cat             A      0
```

Essentially, if duplicate is = 1 then TERM_COMBINED = "Both", else it should = term. So the output will be:

```
TERM_COMBINED
A
BOTH
BOTH
A
```

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
if(df$duplicate == 1) {
  df$TERM_COMBINED <- "Both"
  } else {
  df$TERM_COMBINED <- df$Term
}
```

However, when I run my code I am presented with the following warning and the generated TERM_COMBINED column is just equal to Term

```
Warning message:
In if (o_vShalevClay$Duplicate.Fin == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Additionally, how would I either copy out the data to a new dataframe and only keep 1 of the duplicated entries or remove the duplicates from the dataframe.

Comment: When using multiple values, you need the vectorized `ifelse`. `if` only takes on value and you are passing a vector.  `df$TERM_COMBINED <- ifelse(df$duplicate == 1, "Both", df$Term)` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Axeman. That seems to have worked, but the output are 1, 0 or Both instead of A,B or Both. Can the last part of the ifelse be retained as a string? Would you be able to expand a little more on what you mean by vectorised in this context?

Comment: Sorted it using `as.character(df$Term)`

Comment: See examples in `?ifelse` for the problem with factors. Vectorised basically means "operators on the vector as a whole", i.e. vector of length 5 in, vector of length 5 out. `if` only looks a single (the first) element and then spits a warning.